# finding inverse matrix by set of 4 equations in 4 unknonws

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that inverse of Matrix $A=${a b c d} (2x2 matrix!) $A^{-1}$=$1/(ad-bc)${d -b -c a} (its also 2x2 matrix!) by solving a set of 4 linear equations in 4 unknowns. 
 This is what my homework asked. I know how to find inverse of $A=${a b c d} matrix by adding Identity matrix next to the matrix and making original matrix identity. But i didn't understand `by solving a set of 4 linear equations in 4 unknowns.`part 
 By this sentence, do I have to use other method than i know to find inverse of it ? If so what kind of method teacher might expect ? 
 Second question: how to write a matrix in this site?

Comment: To see how to write matrices, check the only [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/959638/55235) (so far) below. Click the [edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/959638/edit) button to see the code. Instead of `pmatrix` you can also use `bmatrix`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeking $A^{-1}$. Put
$$
A^{-1} := \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_2 \\ a_3 & a_4 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
You want $AA^{-1} = I$ *and* $A^{-1}A = I$. Now, by [If $AB = I$ then $BA = I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i), it is sufficient to solve, say, $AA^{-1} = I$, i.e.
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_2 \\ a_3 & a_4 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},
$$
or equivalently, you must solve the system of $4$ linear equations in the $4$ unkowns $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$ given by
\begin{align}
a a_1 + ba_3 = 1, \\
a a_2 + ba_4 = 0, \\
c a_1 + da_3 = 1, \\
c a_2 + da_4 = 0.
\end{align}
As pointed out in another answer here, this amounts to solving two independent systems of $2$ equations in $2$ unknowns.

To write matrices on this site you can click "edit" on this answer and you will see the Latex code.

Answer (score 2):

You are asked to solve the system of linear equations $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}a &b\\ c& d\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{cc}x& z\\ y& t\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\ 0& 1 \end{array}\right)$$ on the unknowns $x,y,z,t.$ That is:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{r}ax+by=1 \\ cx+dy=0\\az+dt=0\\cz+dt=1\end{array}\right.$$

Note that it is equivalent to solve the following two linear systems:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{r}ax+by=1 \\ cx+dy=0\end{array}\right.$$ and

$$\left\{\begin{array}{r}az+dt=0\\cz+dt=1\end{array}\right.$$